# Site-2-Site Juniper SRX & Zywall

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I've a Juniper SRX 340 on my datacenter and a Zywall USG 100 on my office.
I'd like to build a site-to-site VPN between them, but after a lot of tries I can't still reach the result.

This is the configuration on Juniper side:

```
traceoptions {
    file ike-trace;
}
respond-bad-spi 1;
proposal Ufficio_BG {
    authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
    dh-group group2;
    authentication-algorithm md5;
    encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc;
    lifetime-seconds 3600;
}
policy ike_pol_UfficioBG {
    mode aggressive;
    proposals Ufficio_BG;
    pre-shared-key ascii-text "$9$mPz6B1hcrvuOWxN-wsP5T3Ct"; ## SECRET-DATA
}
gateway gw_UfficioBG {
    ike-policy ike_pol_UfficioBG;
    address 10.10.10.1;
    local-identity inet 20.20.20.1;
    external-interface reth0.0;
    version v1-only;
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------

proposal UfficioBG {
    protocol esp;
    authentication-algorithm hmac-sha-256-128;
    encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
    lifetime-seconds 3600;
    lifetime-kilobytes 4294967294;
}
policy ipsec_pol_UfficioBG {
    perfect-forward-secrecy {
        keys group5;
    }
    proposals UfficioBG;
}
vpn UfficioBG {
    bind-interface st0.2;
    ike {
        gateway gw_UfficioBG;
        ipsec-policy ipsec_pol_UfficioBG;
    }
    establish-tunnels immediately;
}
```

And this one is on Zywall Side:

```
isakmp policy CED_Milano
 activate
 local-ip interface TIM_FC
 peer-ip 20.20.20.1 0.0.0.0
 authentication pre-share
 encrypted-keystring $4$7QS0D3Km$5ZHdWCJz2pBYw1yHb0RQCZHByYwcxfAnFj/C8zZmHeApLK4fOP4a8SWrwDRt0OnZzrF66GMvbNsEqA9slprImix1v0rfHyB0StxbWQzpoh0$
 local-id type ip 10.10.10.1
 peer-id type ip 20.20.20.1
 fall-back-check-interval 300
 lifetime 3600
 mode aggressive
 group2
 no dpd
 transform-set 3des-md5
 xauth type server default deactivate
 no natt
!
crypto map CED_MILANO
 adjust-mss auto
 activate
 ipsec-isakmp CED_Milano
 scenario site-to-site-static
 encapsulation tunnel
 transform-set esp-aes128-sha256
 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
 set pfs group5
 local-policy LAN1_SUBNET
 remote-policy CED
 no conn-check activate
 policy-enforcement
```

Juniper log tells me:

```
Mar 12 08:51:14  fw01 kmd[72691]: IKE negotiation successfully completed. IKE Version: 1, VPN: UfficioBG Gateway: gw_UfficioBG, Local: 20.20.20.1/500, Remote: 10.10.10.1/500, Local IKE-ID: 20.20.20.1, Remote IKE-ID: 10.10.10.1, VR-ID: 0, Role: Initiator
Mar 12 08:51:14  fw01 kmd[72691]: IPSec negotiation failed with error: No proposal chosen. IKE Version: 1, VPN: UfficioBG Gateway: gw_UfficioBG, Local: 20.20.20.1/500, Remote: 10.10.10.1/500, Local IKE-ID: 20.20.20.1, Remote IKE-ID: 10.10.10.1, VR-ID: 0
Mar 12 08:52:13  fw01 kmd[72691]: IPSec negotiation failed with error: No proposal chosen. IKE Version: 1, VPN: UfficioBG Gateway: gw_UfficioBG, Local: 20.20.20.1/500, Remote: 10.10.10.1/500, Local IKE-ID: 20.20.20.1, Remote IKE-ID: 10.10.10.1, VR-ID: 0
Mar 12 08:53:13  fw01 kmd[72691]: IPSec negotiation failed with error: No proposal chosen. IKE Version: 1, VPN: UfficioBG Gateway: gw_UfficioBG, Local: 20.20.20.1/500, Remote: 10.10.10.1/500, Local IKE-ID: 20.20.20.1, Remote IKE-ID: 10.10.10.19, VR-ID: 0
```

And, a this point, I don't understand where is the problem; the error talks about proposals, but I tried different combinations without result.

Anyone has ideas or suggestions?

Thanks to all in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exist next kb [KB24642](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB24642) related to your question:

> This could be attributed to the following:
>
> `The st0 interface needs to be configured under a specific security zone.`
>
> ```
> Even if the st0 interface is unnumbered, it needs to have the following configuration:
>
>     # set interfaces st0.0 family inet
>
> Make sure st0.x interface numbers are used. If you configure st1.0 (instead of st0.1 or st0.2 and so on) then you will get the "no proposal choosen" error and your tunnel will not come up.
> ```